# Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected NODEJS MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

db name: learners
, table: learner_details, columns:
learner_id, learner_name, learner_mail, course_id.

just want to make a POST request on Postman but isnt working.

ERROR:

> ````
> selected',   sqlState: '3D000',   index: 4,   sql: 'SET @learner_id =
> NULL; SET @learner_name = NULL; SET @learner_email =NULL; SET
> @course_id = NULL; CALL learner_create_update( @learner_id,
> @learner_name, @learner_email, @course_id);' }```
> ````

CODE:

```
    let learner = req.body;
    var sql = "SET @learner_id = ?; SET @learner_name = ?; SET @learner_email =?; SET @course_id = ?; CALL learner_create_update( @learner_id, @learner_name, @learner_email, @course_id);";
    mysqlConnection.query(
        sql, 
        [learner.learner_id, learner.learner_name, learner.learner_email, learner.course_id],
        (err, rows, fields) => {
            if( !err )
                rows.forEach(element => {
            if( element.constructor == Array )
                res.send('New Learner ID : ' + element[0].learner_id);
            });
            else 
                console.log(err);
            })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you have two choice

You add a database name to the connection

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    database : 'dbname',
    user     : 'username',
    password : 'password',
});
```

Or you add a query with

```
use dbname;
```

**before** you run all the rest of the queries